# TableLayout Constraint horizontalSpan does not work

Tags: codenameone

When I use horizontalSpan image does not show, however when I use widthPercentage the image perfect shows up.
How can I span the ScaleImageLabel?

My code:

```
    TableLayout tm=new TableLayout(4,6);
    tm.setGrowHorizontally(true);
    Container con=new Container(tm);
    con.setScrollableY(true);
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,con);
    TableLayout.Constraint cs;

    Image icon=profilbillede.scaled(800, -1);
    ScaleImageLabel lb=new ScaleImageLabel(icon);
    lb.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
    con.add(tm.createConstraint().horizontalSpan(2),lb);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works because I removed the span. A table needs to calculate column widths automatically unless you explicitly tell it the with of the column.

When you use span we don't know if the width applies to the 1st or 2nd column so it's ignored with the assumption that you have a reason for spanning and not using one column. In that case you would define the width in a different cell either via preferred size or via the width element.

As a side note there is no need to scale the image before adding it to the `ScaledLabel` you would be doing double the scaling which degrades the appearance of the image.

```
Form hi = new Form("Table", new BorderLayout());
TableLayout tm=new TableLayout(4,6);
tm.setGrowHorizontally(true);
Container con=new Container(tm);
con.setScrollableY(true);
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,con);
TableLayout.Constraint cs;

Image icon=duke.scaled(800, -1);
ScaleImageLabel lb=new ScaleImageLabel(icon);
lb.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
con.add(tm.createConstraint(),lb);
hi.show();
```

[image: Table]

Comment: I was not too specific in what I want. I need an image in the left corner with 2 lines of text to the right of the image, ie spanning the image 2x2 cells. It does not make any sence that the image is not shown at all when spanning.

Comment: More fun. If I first put text labels at columns 0 and then put image at column 4 the image is perfectly shown even though I span horizontal and vertical

Comment: I found my way thanks to your input. By combine verticalspan and widthpercentage I got what I want

Comment: Yes. The thing is that if you don't have an entry in a column the width is effectively 0. Spanned columns are ignored in width calculation because we can't know which column you are referring to so 0 + 0 = 0.